# How to pass a pointer using exec argv in C?

Tags: c, pointers, exec

I'm trying to demonstrate that programs started using `exec` can't derefernce inherited pointers but my pointer looks different. Is this intended?

**p1.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int *pint = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pint = 25;
    printf("[main] pint: @%p = %d\n", pint, *pint);

    int h = fork();

    if(h == 0) {
        (*pint)++;
        printf("[fork] pint: @%p = %d\n", pint, *pint);
        char *fname="./p2";
        char *arg[3];
        arg[0] = "./p2";
        arg[1] = (char*)pint;
        arg[2] = NULL;
        printf("[fork] arg1: @%p = %d\n", arg[1], *arg[1]);
        execvp(fname, arg);
    } else {
        sleep(1);
        printf("[main] pint: @%p = %d\n", pint, *pint);
    }

}
```

**p2.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,void *argv[])
{
    printf("[ p2 ] arg1: @%p\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Here's a sample output that I'm getting:

```
$ ./p1
[main] pint: @0x55de8f6db260 = 25
[fork] pint: @0x55de8f6db260 = 26
[fork] arg1: @0x55de8f6db260 = 26
[ p2 ] arg1: @0x7ffe13b9fc65 // <--- mismatch
[main] pint: @0x55de8f6db260 = 25
```

Comment: `arg[1] = (char*)pint;` You are lying to the `execvp` function. You need to pass it a string yet you are really passing it an `int *`.

Comment: Of course, it is true that you can't pass pointers through exec. So it won't work even if you make it a string and then try to turn it back into a pointer. (That's not what @someprogrammerdude is suggesting. It certainly works if you convert the thing pointed to into a string, provided you can recreate that thing from the string. But that's not passing a pointer.)

Comment: @rici can you provide an example how I can convert the string back into an actual pointer? I used `"%p", pint` to create the string of pointer in main program.

Comment: @d9ngle: Yep. That's an integer encoded in hexadecimal, so you can convert it back to an integer with, for example, strtoull, and then cast it to a pointer. But of course it won't point to the same thing, since that thing no longer exists. It might not even point at mapped memory. But in principle, a pointer is just a integer of some size. (There's no guarantee that `unsigned long long` is big enough to hold a pointer, but in practice it is.)

Comment: @rici I have trouble getting this to work. Here's a code for converting string back to pointer but dereferencing new pointer gives segfault. Can you take a look? https://ideone.com/F6ZJox

Comment: I  don't see any segfault there, although it's quite different from what I suggested, which was to sprintf with conversion `%p` and read the hex back with `strtoull`. Unlike `atoi` `strtoull` can be told to use hex.

Comment: @rici last line gives segfault which I've commented out so you can see the rest of stdout. Any idea why this doesn't work? I'll try with `strtoull` now.

Comment: https://ideone.com/10lIfn

Comment: @rici, thanks got the `strtoull` working already & will try to change `int` type to fix it :)

Comment: The `int` I'm talking about is the one `atoi` returns. And the one `printf %u` prints. It has nothing to with any other `int` in the program.

Comment: Yeah, I know that.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments you pass *must* be strings. That means

```
arg[1] = (char*)pint;
```

is wrong.

You need to create a string, and copy the textual representation of the value into the string.

Something like

```
char arg1[64];
snprintf(arg1, sizeof arg1, "%d", *pint);
arg[1] = arg1;
```

---

The requirement that the arguments are strings also means that `void *argv[]` is wrong as well.

Comment: I want to pass the actual pointer so I'm using `"%p", pint`, how do I turn the string back into a pointer in `p2.c`?

Comment: @d9ngle What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need to pass the pointer itself instead of the value (as a string)?

Comment: @d9ngle Also, if you read e.g. [this `execve` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) you will see that "Memory mappings are not preserved", which means `mmap` based heap allocators will not pass on their memory beyond the `exec` call. The arguments needs to be *copied* to the new image.

Comment: Yeah, I already know that. It's not solving anything in particular, just a *demonstration* of what is already in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by kaylum, rici and Some programmer dude, one needs to convert pointer to string and then cast that string back to pointer to accomplish this, so:

**p1.c:**

```
char arg1[64];
snprintf(arg1, sizeof arg1, "%p", pint);
printf("[fork] arg1: @%s\n", arg1);

arg[0] = "./p2";
arg[1] = arg1;
arg[2] = NULL;
```

**p2.c:**

```
unsigned long long int *pint;
pint = (int*)strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 16);
```